# Did DeepBlue use machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, ai, game

Did IBM's DeepBlue, which defeated a human player in chess in 1997, use machine learning? I am a bit confused by [this article](https://becominghuman.ai/know-your-new-overlords-understanding-the-differences-between-ai-and-machine-learning-660ad936c19e) that says that it is AI, but not ML. Whereas [this article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/forbestechcouncil/2019/05/09/what-deep-blue-and-alphago-can-teach-us-about-explainable-ai/?sh=24337eeb52fd) says it is AI and to some extent ML. Is it the case of an algorithm that is AI but not ML?

Comment: AI is a general term, for example for fast and smart search over a search space, ML is statistical learning. So it is possible to use AI and not ML

Comment: Thank you Nikos! However, my questions is about DeepBlue.

Comment: I am pretty sure it used some kind of AI, but I doubt it used ML

Comment: To link to your articles DeepBlue was not trained using data (or big data) as such was not achievable at that time. Yes it used clever algorithms (which also count as AI), but did not use statistical learning from data which is the definition of ML. Now if one wishes to count bayesian models for the edtimation of some probabilities ML, it is fine, however it is not trained using data (unlike AlphaGo, almost 2 decades later)